# how can i send ENTER/RETURN key with javascript executor code in selenium python?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

Hi all i am new to python selenium, i am in the process of automating a website but unfortunately the search text box of the website does not have any buttons to click once you enter the text

things i tried

1)driver.sendkeys-not working

2)JavaScript executor - just sends the data but no clue how to send the Enter/return key

```
 driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('tau-search__input')[0].value ='" + var+"'");
```

3}Action chains class- tried to send keys but yet no result

also the search icon highlighted here is unable to send data and we can only send data by entering values and clicking on enter at the end
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTSMN.png)

there are no frames there too
please help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input_element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tau-search__input")[0]
input_element.send_keys("your_text_string_input" + Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: hey man thanks for the reply i tried the above method in the begining but unfortunately i am unable to send any data into the field

Comment: What error / exception do you see? Maybe you missing delay / wait before `input_element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tau-search__input")[0]` ?

Comment: umm i kept a sleep(10) and there are no delays it just goes to the element but prints nothing  and there are no errors thats the tricky part

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: https://www.apptio.com/products/targetprocess/targetprocess-free-trial-request/            i have a paid company account in this website

Comment: So, I can't see that page actually? Or that element is on the "get trial" page?

Comment: <input type="text" class="tau-search__input" placeholder="Find entities by text or id" value>              how about a html tag?

Comment: Are you sure that element matches the first match of `tau-search__input` class name?

Comment: Pretty sure it's the first match cause althrough there are elements with tau-search__input class they have search after the tag and I also ran into error while changing the value of zero  in input_element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tau-search__input")[0]

Answer (score 0):

I hope your xpath is wrong, you are pointing to the search icon not the search box. please share us the element screenshot if possible. your url is not working for us.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I just discovered another way to get my result apparently the website does give excel report in the way I wanted so apparently I  changed my approach for now ...will follow up on the screen shot if possible